# Using svg background images in Trigger.io and android 4.4

Tags: css, svg, trigger.io, android-4.4-kitkat

svg background images are not displayed in android 4.4.
This is only a problem when trying to load them from as local recourse. svgs are displayed when loaded from a remote url.

Answer (score -1):

check out your css file and make sure you are calling `backgound-size` AFTER `background`.
More information is found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html#BackgroundSize

Comment: I get the same issue still